# R Neural Net Issues

Tags: r

Here is the updated code.   My issue is with the output of "results".  I'll post below as the format for readability.

```
library("neuralnet")
    library("ggplot2")
    setwd("C:/Users/Aaron/Documents/UMUC/R/Data For Assignments")
    trainset <- read.csv("SOTS.csv")
    head(trainset)
    ## val data classification
    str(trainset) 
    ## building the neural network
    risknet <- neuralnet(Overall.Risk.Value ~ Finance + Personnel + Information.Dissemenation.C, trainset, hidden = 10, lifesign = "minimal", linear.output = FALSE, threshold = 0.1)
    ##plot nn
    plot(risknet, rep="best")

    ##import scoring set
    score_set <- read.csv("SOSS.csv")
    ##select subsets-training and scoring match
    score_test <- subset(score_set, select = c("Finance", "Personnel", "Information.Dissemenation.C"))
    ##display values of score_test

    head(score_test)
    ##neural network compute function score_test and the neural net "risknet"
    risknet.results <- compute(risknet, score_test)

    ##Actual value of Overall.Risk.Value variable wanting to predict. net.result = a matrix containing the overall result of the neural network
    results <- data.frame(Actual = score_set$Overall.Risk.Value, Prediction = risknet.results$net.result)
    results[1:14, ]
```

The output of results is not as expected.  For instance, the actual data is a number between 5 and 8, whereas "Prediction" displays outputs of .9995...for each result.

Thanks again for the help.

Comment: What's your so called "scoring" set? A validation set or a test set?

Comment: The scoring set is the exact same data as the training set (shown within the variable risknet).  The only difference is the value for Overall.Risk.Value

Answer (score 0):

This is how you train and predict:

1. Use training data to learn model parameters (the variable `risknet` in your case)
2. Use parameters to predict scores on test data

[Here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/using-neural-networks-for-credit-scoring-a-simple-example/) is an example very much similar to yours that explains how this is done.

Answer (score 0):

The default activation function in neuralnet is "logistic". When linear.output is set as FALSE, it ensures that the output is mapped by the activation function to the interval [0,1].(R_Journal (neuralnet)- Frauke Günther)

I just updated linear.output=TRUE in your code and final result looks much better.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Was this a comment for my answer? If you find any answer that helps, add a coment and upvote/aceept the answer instead of posting a new one!